# Splitting an array and using the value after the equal sign

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the jquery below and a function that returns an array. 
The array I receive for `myAnswers = ["Question 1=null", "Question 2=null", "Question 3=yes", "Question 4=yes", "Question 5=yes"]`

In my for loop below, I want to process the values after the "=" for each array element

### Example:

```
if question 1 = null ... do something
elseif question 1 = yes .. do another thing
```

How can I split this so that I will be able to test the values after the `=` sign?

```
            $('#Continue').click(function() {
                var myAnswers = CheckRadioButtons(); 

                for (i = 0; i < myAnswers.length; i++) {       
                    var splitResult = myAnswers[1].split('=');
                    var expectedValue = splitResult[1];
                }
            });


            function CheckRadioButtons() {    
                var $rb = $('input:radio');
                var tempArray = new Array();
                var questionNo = 0;
                for (var i = 0; i < $rb.length; i += 2) {
                    ...some logic
                }
                return tempArray;
            }
```

Comment: your for loop is broken : you loop on `i` but never use it

Comment: yeah in the first loop you want `myAnswers[i]`

Comment: If possible you should store some objects rather than strings. Consider a answer object with the following structure : `{ question: "question4", answer: true}` for a yes, `{ question: "question1", answer: null}` for a missing answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `i` in `myAnswers[]`

```
 for (i = 0; i < myAnswers.length; i++) {       
     var splitResult = myAnswers[i].split('=');
     var expectedValue = splitResult[1];

     // Note: Both null and yes will be a string.
     if(expectedValue=="null"){ // Do something}
     else if(expectedValue=="yes") { // Do something else }
 }
```

Comment: I missed the i. Thanks. I changed it and works very well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, where `value` is e.g. `"Question 1=null"`

```
value.split('=')[1] //Right hand side
```